# How to keep SQLAlchemy relationships functional in subclasses?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've written an SQLAlchemy application that consists of a "backend" and a "frontend" (The backend is a service that populates a database, and the frontend is a WSGI web application presenting that data).

Both frontend and backend import a common module ("models") that contains the SQLAlchemy ORM class definitions and nothing else. In the frontend and backend  I define subclasses of the ORM base classes which add methods to do the actual work of the application. I find this an elegant and clean solution to separate the common things (database structure) from the specifics (data entry and retrieval).

However, this obviously breaks SQLAlchemy's relationships, which are defined in the "models" module and therefore don't know about the derived classes and their methods. Below is an example.

So my question is: How can I add module-specific methods to ORM (sub)classes and still use SQLAlchemy's relationships?

```
models.py
# pure SQLAlchemy ORM declarations, imported by various modules

class JobT(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    tool = relationship('ToolT', back_populates="jobs", uselist=False)

class ToolT(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    jobs = relationship('JobT', back_populates="tool")

backend.py
# defines derived classes that add actual functionality to the objects

from models import ToolT, JobT

class Tool(ToolT):
    def fancy_method(self):
        pass

class Job(JobT):
    def do_stuff(self):
        foo = self.tool.fancy_method()

>>> job = Job(...)
>>> job.do_stuff()

AttributeError: 'ToolT' object has no attribute 'do_stuff'
```

(I know why this error occurs. No explanation required).

Comment: Don't use inheritance, but instead collect your business methods somewhere else is my opinion on this subject.

Comment: Do you mean to define the business methods as normal functions and make them classmethods using setattr()? It works, but seems inelegant/ugly.

Comment: No `setattr()` hackery required, just keep your business methods in their own module and call upon your model objects. But again, this is just an opinion.